# Set Up AXFR on Debian and linode

Tags: debian, bind

getting errors after following this tutorial: 
https://www.linode.com/docs/websites/cms/set-up-dns-services-on-cpanel/

```
DNS servers responded   
ERROR: One or more of your nameservers did not respond:
The ones that did not respond are:
162.159.27.72 162.159.26.99 162.159.24.25 162.159.24.39 162.159.25.129
```

I could use the nameservers listed below to performe recursive queries. It may be that I am wrong but the chances of that are low. You should not have nameservers that allow recursive queries as this will allow almost anyone to use your nameservers and can cause problems. Problem record(s) are:

```
162.159.26.99
162.159.24.39
162.159.24.25
162.159.27.72
162.159.25.129
```

what have I done so far:

1) add name servers at my domain registrar

```
ns1.example.com
ns2.example.com
ns1.linode.com
ns2.linode.com
ns3.linode.com
ns4.linode.com
ns5.linode.com
```

2) update named.conf.options file

3) add a slave zone

`nano /etc/bind/named.conf.options`

```
options {
        directory "/var/cache/bind";

        // If there is a firewall between you and nameservers you want
        // to talk to, you may need to fix the firewall to allow multiple
        // ports to talk.  See http://www.kb.cert.org/vuls/id/800113

        // If your ISP provided one or more IP addresses for stable
        // nameservers, you probably want to use them as forwarders.
        // Uncomment the following block, and insert the addresses replacing
        // the all-0's placeholder.

        // forwarders {
        //      0.0.0.0;
        // };

        //========================================================================
        // If BIND logs error messages about the root key being expired,
        // you will need to update your keys.  See https://www.isc.org/bind-keys
        //========================================================================
        dnssec-enable yes;
        dnssec-validation yes;
        dnssec-lookaside auto;

        auth-nxdomain no;    # conform to RFC1035
        listen-on-v6 { any; };


        allow-transfer {
     104.237.137.10;
     65.19.178.10;
     75.127.96.10;
     207.192.70.10;
     109.74.194.10;
     2600:3c00::a;
     2600:3c01::a;
     2600:3c02::a;
     2600:3c03::a;
     2a01:7e00::a;
 };
 also-notify {
     104.237.137.10;
     65.19.178.10;
     75.127.96.10;
     207.192.70.10;
     109.74.194.10;
     2600:3c00::a;
     2600:3c01::a;
     2600:3c02::a;
     2600:3c03::a;
     2a01:7e00::a;
 };

        // Do not make public version of BIND
        version none;
};
```

dig

```
; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4-Debian <<>> axfr @162.159.27.72 revelhost.net
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
; Transfer failed.
```

Comment: What kind of response do you get from the slave servers if you query them directly (using eg dig)?

Comment: check out the updated question with dig

Comment: That doesn't look like a representative query for the problem you were describing. Something like `dig @162.159.27.72 example.com +norec`, maybe?

Comment: check now question updated

Comment: Do you mind explaining what you are trying to accomplish? Did you remember to create the A registries in your registrar for the NS domains (ns1.example.com and ns2.example.com)? Also the file is `/etc/named.conf` not `named.conf.options` and you could check everything is ok with `named-checkconf /etc/named.conf`

Comment: I want to Use Linode’s DNS Manager as a Slave,  on debian the file is "named.conf.options"  and I did check with named-checkconf, I get nothing back

Comment: In the earlier version of the question where you had the dig output for a regular query we could see that you get `SERVFAIL` back which suggests that the zone exists but something is wrong. Quite possibly they are unable to perform the zone transfer. Can you check and double-check that you have given them the correct information about your zone (ie, correct master ip and obviously correct zone name) and check your own logs for traces of their attempted zone transfers?

Comment: when you say them do you mean linode or registrar? I have access to bind server

Comment: Do I need to add A record at my DNS for ns1.linode.com
ns2.linode.com
ns3.linode.com
ns4.linode.com
ns5.linode.com

Comment: I meant the operator of the slave servers (Linode in this case, if I understand correctly)

Comment: yes I added the correct  Slave Zone at linode DNS manager

Comment: As in that it was already correct? Unless you mean that you just fixed something and it now works, clearly something is wrong either on your end or on their end. What about your logs, any hints as to what happens to their zone transfers?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80490/discussion-between-velvetink-and-hakan-lindqvist).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the discussion of the question in comments and chat, it turned out that the `named` logs said things such as

```
client 104.237.137.10#45797 (example.com): zone transfer 'example.com/AXFR/IN' denied
```

After further questions about that the named config actually contained, it turned out that the `allow-transfer` directive on the global-level (inside `options`) shown in the question was actually overridden on the zone level (inside the relevant `zone`) to not allow these slave nameservers.